# How do I reorder and array and setValues of the newly ordered array into my spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm pulling data from one sheet as an array and then putting it into anther sheet, but the values need to be in a different order.

If the source array `searchData` where `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` I need to place the values `pastearray` into the second sheet in the order `[7,1,7,4,3,0,2,7,5]`. I have three problems, one is that the order is changed, the second is that there are values repeated in the `pastearray` (namely the 7th value), and the third is that several of the values pulled from `searchData` are null/blank, in this case, the 7s.

I am doing this for a class project. I am just learning about arrays and still having trouble completely grasping how to manipulate them. I have already tried 1D, 2D, 3D conversion, at least I think that is what I was doing...not sure if I was correct. I have verified that everything else in the script works except for the final `pasteRange.setValues(pastearray[0]);`.

My log shows that `pastearray` contains:

```
[[null], [Language Arts 6], [null], [A/1], [6.0], [67511.0], [Layton, B], [blayton@acedu.org]]
```

I also tried:

```
["Language Arts 6", "A/1", "6.0", "67511.0", "Layton, B", "blayton@questac.org"]
```

I've tried removing the "null" values or leaving them in. I've tried straight grabbing a row of values and setting them, and that worked fine as long as I don't try to re-arrange them.

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.range.getA1Notation() == 'F3' && 
      e.range.getSheet().getName() == 'Class Information and Roster') {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var paste2 = ss.getSheetByName("Class Information and Roster");
    var tclimport = ss.getSheetByName("TeacherClassListImport");

    var classID = e.range.getValue();//Get class id value

    Logger.log(classID);

    paste2.getRange(6,1,31,10).clearContent();//clear all old info just in case

    //access the list of all classes


    var lr = tclimport.getLastRow();
    var searchData = tclimport.getRange(1,1,lr,7).getValues(); //make an array of all the classes available

    //Logger.log(searchData);

    //Find the row with that class ID
    for (var i = 0; i < searchData.length; i++) {
      if(searchData[i][0]==classID){
        Logger.log(i+1);
        //Logger.log(searchData);


        var pastearray = [[searchData[i][7]],[searchData[i][1]], [searchData[i][7]], [searchData[i][4]], [searchData[i][3]], [searchData[i][0]], [searchData[i][2]], [searchData[i][7]], [searchData[i][5]]];
        Logger.log(pastearray);

      //Copy in info from class ID list
        var pasteRange = paste2.getRange(3,1,1,9);

        pasteRange.setValues(pastearray); 
         }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm sure you will cringe looking at my code since it is so rudimentary, but it works the way I understand...all except the final `setValues()`.

The idea of this code is that you enter a class ID number in cell F3. `OnEdit` triggers the script to find the details about that class in the sheet "TeacherClassListImport", copy those values and returns the values in row 3 in a different order class name, time period, level, class ID, teacher name, and teacher email. It will overwrite the same cell F3 with the same class ID unless there is a better way to do it. The 7th is a null/blank cell. I'm not sure that it even has to be there except for proper spacing to fit the template.

Any help is appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `pasteRange` is 1 row long and 9 columns wide.
Your `pastearray` is 9 rows long and 1 column wide.

You have

```js
var pastearray = [
  [searchData[i][7]], [searchData[i][1]], [searchData[i][7]],
  [searchData[i][4]], [searchData[i][3]], [searchData[i][0]],
  [searchData[i][2]], [searchData[i][7]], [searchData[i][5]]
];
```

but your range wants

```js
var pastearray = [[
  searchData[i][7], searchData[i][1], searchData[i][7],
  searchData[i][4], searchData[i][3], searchData[i][0],
  searchData[i][2], searchData[i][7], searchData[i][5]
]];
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you! I knew it was something to do with those [ ] but could not figure out the right combination. I think I tried every combination except that one.  Now it is working and setting these values...    **A3: undefined B3:Language Arts 6 C3:undefined D3:A/4 E3:6     F3:67513 G3:Layton, B H3:undefined    I3:blayton@eduac.org**  Is there anyway to get the **undefined** values to set as blank or "" instead? You have been so helpful!

Comment: I still could use help with getting the **undefined** to show up as blank instead, but I think I finally get the [ ].  One set for the out edges of the entire array, another inner set for each row, and each cell in the row is just divided by ,   I know this is elementary to most of you, but this was a revolation to me, LOL. Thanks for the help understanding this.

Comment: @JLBJones use `||` like this: `[searchData[I][7] || ""]` to provide "" as a default value.

Comment: Thank you again! You are a wealth of knowledge. Best to you!